# Class org.apache.spark.sql.types.SQLUserDefinedType not found - continuing with a stub

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a basic spark mllib program as follows.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors


class Sample {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("helloApp").setMaster("local")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt")
  val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()

  // Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
  val numClusters = 2
  val numIterations = 20
  val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)

  // Export to PMML
  println("PMML Model:\n" + clusters.toPMML)
}
```

I have manually added `spark-core` , `spark-mllib` and `spark-sql` to the project class path through intellij all having version 1.5.0.

I am getting the below error when I run the program? any idea what's wrong?

> Error:scalac: error while loading Vector, Missing dependency 'bad
>   symbolic reference. A signature in Vector.class refers to term types
>   in package org.apache.spark.sql which is not available. It may be
>   completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the
>   classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling
>   Vector.class.', required by
>   /home/fazlann/Downloads/spark-mllib_2.10-1.5.0.jar(org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vector.class

Comment: What do you mean by "manually added"?

Comment: i added the jars to the class path using module settings option

Answer (score 1):

DesirePRG. I have met the same problem as yours. The solution is to import some jar which assemble the spark and hadoop, such as **spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar**, then it could work properly.